# C dynamic vector of struct

Tags: c, vector, dynamic, struct

I have the following struct for a dynamic vector:

```
typedef struct {
    TElement *data;
    int len;
}Vector;
```

And 2 functions, one to initialize the vector and the other one to append an element:

```
Vector *initVector()
{
    Vector *v;
    v = malloc(sizeof(TElement));
    v->len = 0;
    return v;
}
void append(Vector *v, TElement element)
{
    v = (Vector *)realloc(v, (v->len + 1) * sizeof(TElement));
    v->data[v->len++] = element;
}
```

When i try to append an element, the program crashes and I don't know why, any ideas?

Comment: What did you discover when you tried to debug this?

Comment: `v = malloc(sizeof(TElement))`....fishy...

Comment: Why `sizeof(TElement)`? It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Why do you cast the result of `realloc`, but not of `malloc`? Write consistent code! You should not cast `void *` to/from other pointers in C in general, so remove that useless (and potentially problematic) cast.

Comment: And why not use a `struct` with _flexible array member_?

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `v` is of type `Vector *`, and you're allocating memory as of the size of `TElement`, which is wrong.

Change

```
v = malloc(sizeof(TElement));
```

to

```
v = malloc(sizeof*v);
```

That said,

- Always check for the success of `malloc()` by checking the returned pointer against NULL to avoid any possible UB, in case `malloc()` failed.
- `p = realloc(p,...)` style is very bad, because, in case `realloc()` fails, you'll end up losing the actual pointer, too. Catch the return value of `realloc()` in a temporary pointer, check against NULL for success and then assign back to the original pointer.

Answer (score 0):

- In function `initVector()`, allocate `sizeof(Vector)` instead of `sizeof(TElement)`
- In function `append`, modify `v->data` instead of `v` and remove the unneeded and harmful cast.

corrected code:

```
Vector *initVector()
{
    Vector *v;
    v = malloc(sizeof(*v));
    v->len = 0;
    return v;
}
void append(Vector *v, TElement element)
{
    v->data = realloc(v->data, (v->len + 1) * sizeof(TElement));
    v->data[v->len++] = element;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your initVector you ought to reserve space for one `Vector`. Furthermore, you *must* set `v->data` to `NULL`, or valid allocated pointer, otherwise your code would have undefined behaviour.

```
Vector *initVector() {
    Vector *v;
    v = malloc(sizeof Vector);
    if (! v) {
        /* error: malloc failed */
    }
    v->data = 0;
    v->len = 0;
    return v;
}
```

In `append` you ought to be resizing the area pointed to by `data`, not the `Vector` allocation itself:

```
void append(Vector *v, TElement element) {
    TElement *new_p = realloc(v->data, (v->len + 1) * sizeof(TElement));

    if (!new_p) {
        /* error: malloc failed */
    }
    v->data = new_p;
    v->data[v->len++] = element;
}
```

It is also a very good idea to check the return value of `malloc`; if not else, it makes sense to abort there after printing a sensible message rather than crashing with incomprehensible `SIGSEGV`.

---

Also, growing the vector one item a time means that item insertion will have O(n) time complexity on a container with `n` items. It is preferable to allocate the space in geometric progressions (for example when you need to resize the allocation, then expand the allocation by a factor of 1.5 or 2, not by a constant amount), and start from some larger minimum allocation of 8 or 16 items.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the following

```
Vector *initVector()
{
    Vector *v = malloc( sizeof( Vector ) );
                                 ^^^^^^
    if ( v != NULL )
    {
        v->len = 0;
        v->data = NULL;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }

    return v;
}

void append( Vector *v, TElement element )
{
    TElement *tmp = realloc( v->data, ( v->len + 1 ) * sizeof( TElement ) );
                             ^^^^^^^^    
    if ( tmp != NULL )
    {
        v->data = tmp;
        v->data[len++] = element;
    }
}
```

The return type of the last function can be changed from `void` to `int` to report whether the new element was appended. For example

```
int append( Vector *v, TElement element )
{
    int success;

    TElement *tmp = realloc( v->data, ( v->len + 1 ) * sizeof( TElement ) );
                             ^^^^^^^^    
    if ( ( success = tmp != NULL ) )
    {
        v->data = tmp;
        v->data[len++] = element;
    }

    return success;
}
```